# Transform a post request to a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, post

I have a questionnaire on `javascript(post request)` and need to acquire the user's answers and then transform them into a `JSON` file, so far, I've tried this but I have no idea how to proceed, my code is down below.

```js
exports.answers= (req, res) =>{
    async function getISS(){
        const response = await fetch(req);
        const data =await response.json();
        console.log(data);
    }
    getISS();
    console.log(req.text);
    let resultado =[data];
    res.send(resultado);
};
```

The answers come from a survey like this 
[this is the survey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPCBS.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please consider adding your code to the question as a code block or, even better, a snippet. That makes it easier for potential answerers to see and also allows them to copy/paste it into their own answer.

Comment: Thx for the advise, this is my very first question and I'm still learning, so every comment on how to improve the quality of my questions it's well appreciated :D

Comment: Where are the user's answers coming from? From the code I can't tell if you are fetching the answers from the server, and trying to display them, or if you have an HTML form that the user is filling up and you want to send to the server as JSON, on form submission.

Comment: The answers come from an HTML form that the user's filling up like the picture I just upload, thx for the help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to send the form data to the server.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('my-form'),
  url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users';

form.onsubmit = submit;

function submit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData(form),
    data = {};

  // Get a JSON object from the form data
  formData.forEach((value, key) => {
    data[key] = value;
  });

  // Using fetch and await/async
  postData(url, data)
    .then(res => {
      console.log('Fetch await/async response is: ' + JSON.stringify(res)); // JSON data parsed by `response.json()` call
    });

  // Using fetch / then
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
  }).then(
    res => res.json()
  ).then(json => console.log('Fetch / then response is: ' + JSON.stringify(json)));


  // Using XMLHttpRequest
  const req = new XMLHttpRequest();

  req.open('POST', url, true);

  req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

  req.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 201) {

      console.log('XMLHttpRequest response is: ' + req.response);

    }

  }

  req.send(JSON.stringify(data));

}

/*
 * This is the example function on the MDN site for fetch
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
 */
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return await response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}
```

```html
<form action="survey" id="my-form">

  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

  <label for="job">Job</label>
  <input type="text" name="job" id="job">

  <button>Submit</button>

</form>
```

Any of the above methods should work to send your form data to the server as JSON. I have used an online API to demonstrate.